# Read (custom) EXIF data from png file

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

For an app I'm trying to parse a vcf-File with all of the colleagues of my firm. Some of them have no real photo and instead automatically get a dummy photo inserted. Now in order to make the app future proof, I don't want to check for a resolution of 500x500 which right now would work. The idea by the department responsible for the vcf generation was to add a comment to the dummy photo base file they always use. I tried reading that in Swift, but have no luck as you can see in my test playground code:

```
import UIKit
import ImageIO

let photo = UIImage(named: "bild")!
let photoData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo)!
let base64String = photoData.base64EncodedString()

let photoSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(photoData as CFData, nil)!
for (key, value) in CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(photoSource, 0, nil) as! [String : Any] {
    print("\(key): \(value)")
}
```

Output:

```
PixelWidth: 500
Depth: 8
ProfileName: sRGB IEC61966-2.1
HasAlpha: 1
ColorModel: RGB
{PNG}: {
    Chromaticities =     (
        "0.3127",
        "0.329",
        "0.64",
        "0.33",
        "0.3",
        "0.6000000000000001",
        "0.15",
        "0.06"
    );
    Gamma = "0.45455";
    InterlaceType = 0;
    sRGBIntent = 0;
}
PixelHeight: 500
```

The output of `exiftool` in Terminal meanwhile shows this on the same image (see especially `User Comment` and `Document Name` (Custom Field):

```
➔ exiftool bild.png
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.50
File Name                       : bild.png
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 4.2 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2017:05:06 12:51:23+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2017:05:06 12:51:24+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2017:05:06 12:51:23+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : PNG
File Type Extension             : png
MIME Type                       : image/png
Image Width                     : 500
Image Height                    : 500
Bit Depth                       : 8
Color Type                      : Palette
Compression                     : Deflate/Inflate
Filter                          : Adaptive
Interlace                       : Noninterlaced
Palette                         : (Binary data 477 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Transparency                    : 0
Background Color                : 0
Pixels Per Unit X               : 2835
Pixels Per Unit Y               : 2835
Pixel Units                     : meters
Modify Date                     : 2017:05:05 08:04:36
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Document Name                   : dummy
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
Exif Version                    : 0231
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
User Comment                    : dummy
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : Uncalibrated
Image Size                      : 500x500
Megapixels                      : 0.250
```

I already tried accessing the User Comment by using kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment, but this returns nil and I guess it would only return some value, if the above code also worked as expected:

```
let userComment = dict[kCGImagePropertyExifUserComment as String] // User Comment is set --> but this returns nil
let pixelWidth = dict[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth as String] // As a reference that this does normally work --> shows 500 as expected
```

**Do you have any suggestions how to add a comment to the image that is readable with Swift code?**

Comment: PNGs don't contain EXIF. The PNG format has its own metadata chunks which `exiftool` can read, but `CoreImage` not necessarily. However it's not that hard to read them via `libpng`.

Comment: Okay, that explains why I can't read them, but how would I go about importing `libpng` in my iOS app to get access to that metadata on an iPhone?

Comment: How about cocoapods? https://cocoapods.org/pods/libpng

Comment: Ah, didn't see that (I'm a Carthage user avoiding CocoaPods as much as possible). I will look into that although I'm hoping to find another solution without a framework or to find an implementation that supports Carthage.

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete example showing how to create an image, save it as a PNG with metadata, then retrieve that metadata from the file.  You should be able to paste this into an iOS Playground.

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import ImageIO
import MobileCoreServices

var str = "Hello, playground"

if let image = createImage() {
    let pngDictionary : NSDictionary =      [
        kCGImagePropertyPNGTitle  : "Smile for the Camera",
        kCGImagePropertyPNGAuthor  : "Smiles-R-Us",
        kCGImagePropertyPNGCopyright  : "©2017 Smiles-R-Us",
        kCGImagePropertyPNGCreationTime  : String(describing: Date()),
        kCGImagePropertyPNGDescription  : "Have a Nice Day!"
    ]

    let imageMetadata : NSDictionary = [ kCGImagePropertyPNGDictionary : pngDictionary ]

    let tempURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory
    let filePath = tempURL.appendingPathComponent("Smile.png") as NSURL

    let imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(filePath, kUTTypePNG, 1, nil)
    if let destination = imageDestination {
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image.cgImage!, imageMetadata)
        CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
    }

    if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(filePath, nil) {
     print (CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil))
    }

    print(filePath)
}

func createImage() -> UIImage? {
    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
    if let cgContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        let inset = bounds.insetBy(dx: 20, dy: 20)

        cgContext.clear(bounds)
        cgContext.saveGState()
        cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        cgContext.setLineWidth(2.0)
        cgContext.strokeEllipse(in: inset)
        let eyeLevel = inset.maxY - (inset.height * 0.618)
        cgContext.fillEllipse(in: CGRect(x: inset.minX + inset.width * 0.3,
                                         y: eyeLevel, width: 10, height: 10))
        cgContext.fillEllipse(in: CGRect(x: inset.minX + inset.width * 0.6,
                                         y: eyeLevel, width: 10, height: 10))
        cgContext.addArc(center: CGPoint(x:inset.midX, y:inset.midY), radius: (inset.width/2.0 - 20), startAngle: 2.61, endAngle: 0.52, clockwise: true)
        cgContext.strokePath()
    }
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Comment: This is indeed working as long as I stay in the playground and immediately read from the file. If I take the generated Smile.png, drag it to the ressources folder of the playground and read the metadata from that file it strips it of all the fields Xcode deems unnecessary. Therefore I sadly can't use it as a solution to save the photos in the contacts files for the app.